# Is there any way to Move applications in phone memory to SD Card?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, insufficient-memory, whatsapp-messenger, app2sd

I'm using *Samsung Galaxy fit GTS5670* running on Android 2.3.6.

After installing *Whatsapp Messenger* of 13.36 MB, it was installed to phone memory. I got a total of 180 MB internal storage, and just 3.3 MB left.

Is there any way to move Whatsapp from phone memory to SDCard?

Comment: I've just added the `app2sd` tag to your question. For some first aid, I recommend to read [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) first. That should get you started. If you're still stuck, please [edit] your question and describe what you've tried and *where* you're stuck, so we will see if we can help. If you solved it, please answer your question and let us know what exactly you did. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have your phone rooted and secondary partition, you can use [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD).It's good alternative to use.

Answer (score 0):

Okay go to your home screen click on menu then go to settings, scroll down to manage applications or manage apps... click on that then u will be able to see downloaded apps, then apps on your phone storage, and more to your right u will see apps on your sd card go on to phone storage u where u will see all apps that are stored to ur internal memory/phone storage.. and click on the apps u wish to move to ur sd card and it will have all options saying, force stop, uninstall, move to sdcard/phone storage and then clear data... what u want is move to sd card so click that then verify by pushing 'ok' and there u have it. Hope this helped. :)

Comment: Note that apps must actively support this – so not all apps can be moved this way. I don't know whether Whatsapp (the OP wants to move this) does support App2SD.

Comment: still cannot move whatsapp...

Answer (score -1):

If you have rooted your phone use a root explorer to go to data > data> locate the whatsapp folder > files > logs > delete all the files there and you are good to go.